# gmaps4rails 2.4.6 unCaught Reference Error: Gmaps not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I have spent hours reading solutions on StackOverflow and tried everything but I still haven't found the solution.

I'm getting

> unCaught Reference Error: Gmaps not defined

From

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
```

I have re-arranged my script tags numerous times to try and fix this. They now sit in my `'application.html.erb'` layout which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
  Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title>NomadSpaces</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Christopher Dodd">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
  <%= favicon_link_tag '/favicon.ico' %>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag('application', :media => 'all') %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag('spaces', :media => 'all') %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= yield :javascripts %> // Code that calls Gmaps

  <%= javascript_include_tag 'gmaps_api.js' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'markerclusterer_packed.js' %>


</head>

<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

My application.js file looks like this:

```
    // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

The offending function in detail:

```
handler.buildMap({
            internal: {id: 'sidebar_builder'},
            provider: {
                zoom: 15,
                center:    new google.maps.LatLng(53.385873, -1.471471),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                styles:    mapStyle
            }
        }, function(){
            var json_array = <%=raw @hash.to_json %>;

            var markers = handler.addMarkers(json_array);

            _.each(json_array, function(json, index){
                json.marker = markers[index];
            });

            createSidebar(json_array);
            handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
            handler.fitMapToBounds();
        });
```

Space in which the map should display:

```
<div class="row">

    <div id="map-area">
      <div id="sidebar_builder" class="visible"></div>
      <div class="ball"></div>
      <p class="loading">LOADING SPACES</p>
    </div>
    <div id='sidebar_container'></div>

  </div>
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried restarting your server?

Comment: Do you have this code after handler = Gmaps.build('Google'); ?`handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers([
    {
      "lat": 0,
      "lng": 0,
      "picture": {
        "url": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
        "width":  36,
        "height": 36
      },
      "infowindow": "hello!"
    }
  ]);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});`

Comment: This is what I have:
handler.buildMap({
            internal: {id: 'sidebar_builder'},
            provider: {
                zoom: 15,
                center:    new google.maps.LatLng(53.385873, -1.471471),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                styles:    mapStyle
            }
        }, function(){
            var json_array = <%=raw @hash.to_json %>;

            var markers = handler.addMarkers(json_array);

            _.each(json_array, function(json, index){
                json.marker = markers[index];
            });

Comment: Then: 
    createSidebar(json_array);
                handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
                handler.fitMapToBounds();

Comment: I don't want to read that, lol. Add it to your question formatted all nicely?

Comment: Sorry. Bit of a noob at StackOverflow

Comment: I'll just update the question

Answer (score 0):

I had a friend look over my project and found that cause of the error was that `application.js` was not compiling and therefore the gmaps javascript was not loaded onto the page.

Armed with this knowledge, we went back to Stack Overflow and tried changing the ruby version to fix this. Unfortunately, that didn't work.

To solve the issue, I've started a new rails project and copied the important code from the old project. My `application.js` file is now loading correctly and everything is working again.